# Want to use both silent push notification and remote push notification based on app state

Tags: ios, push-notification, silent

Is it possible to use silent push notification when the app is in foreground and remote push notification (with alerts) when the app is in background or its killed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible.
You need to read the following official Apple Documentation on this

[ApplePushService](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

https://developer.apple.com/notifications/